# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items' (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-3.5, urllib

I am trying to post data to api of website using this code:

```
import requests as r
import json


load={"accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
"accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
"accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
"content-length": "40",
"content-type": "application/json",
"origin": "www.mysite.com",
"referer": "www.mysite.com",
"sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
"sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
"sec-fetch-site": "cross-site",
"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36 Edg/83.0.478.37",
}

pd={"version"="1.0"}
ro = r.post("api.mysite.com", headers=json.dumps(load),data=pd)


print(ro.status_code, ro.reason)
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
    ro = r.post("https://api.mysite.com", headers=json.dumps(load),data=pd)
  File "C:\Users\ajay1998A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 119, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ajay1998A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in reques
t
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ajay1998A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 516, in
request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
File "C:\Users\ajay1998A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 459, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "C:\Users\ajay1998A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 315, in prepare
    self.prepare_headers(headers)
  File "C:\Users\ajay1998A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 447, in prepare_headers
for header in headers.items():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I checked the type of load and it's dictionary.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The code seems okay, did you try clearing your `*.pyc` files?

Comment: Yes I did, same error, I removed json.loads and just passed headers as it is but it's giving 403 code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since as you say, your load object is already a dictionary (which is json serializable, and has an items attribute) by writing

```
headers = json.dumps(load)
```

the json.dumps method is JSON encoding your load object into a string (which does not have an item method)

Try

```
headers = load
```

instead

Comment: Thank you it worked, but it keeps giving me 403 forbidden. Any idea why?

Comment: This is an error returned by the API which typically means that either you do not have access to the method or that you need to pass in some type of authentication in your request.

Comment: I passed the api key in header but still same error.